# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function whose sole purpose is to fetch some data when a button is pressed and it's called multiple times. This is the function code:

```
 Function GetData2(ByVal clientNo As Integer) As List(Of SocioInfo)


    Dim theResults2 = New List(Of SocioInfo)
    Dim connStr = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"


    Using conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)

        Dim sql = "SELECT  [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [CustInfo] Where ([NumCuenta] = @SocioNum)"
        Dim sql2 = "SELECT [AcctName], [AcctNum], [NewAcct], [Balance] From [ACCT_NEW] Where ([AcctNum] =  @SocioNum)"
        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim sqlCmd2 = New SqlCommand(sql2, conn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocioNum", CDbl(txtInput.Text))
        sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocioNum", CDbl(txtInput.Text))



        conn.Open()

        Dim rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim rdr2 = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader

        While rdr.Read
            theResults2.Add(New SocioInfo With {
                           .Nombre = rdr.GetString(0),
                           .LastName = rdr.GetString(1)
})

        End While
        While rdr2.Read
            theResults2.Add(New SocioInfo With {
                                         .CuentaName = rdr.GetString(0),
                                          .AcctNum = rdr.GetValue(1),
                                          .AcctFull = rdr2.GetValue(2),
                                         .Balance = rdr2.GetValue(3)
                        })


        End While

    End Using

    Return theResults2

End Function
```

I am not 100% sure if this is the best way to do this (basically need to get data from two different tables). Thing is, while `Rdr` shows me no error, `Rdr2` just blows in the face. The exception is this:

```
Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second loop you are trying to use the first SqlDataReader but this is not possible because the first loop has already reached the end of the input data.

If you need joined data between the two tables a better approach is to use just one query using the JOIN operator. This query works assuming that each customer in the CustInfo table has one account in the ACCT_NEW table

```
Dim sql = "SELECT  c.FirstName, c.LastName, a.AcctName, a.AcctNum, a.NewAcct, a.Balance " & _
          "FROM CustInfo c INNER JOIN ACCT_NEW a ON a.AcctNum = c.NumCuenta "  & _
          "WHERE NumCuenta = @SocioNum "


Using conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)

    Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocioNum", CDbl(txtInput.Text))
    conn.Open()
    Dim rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

    While rdr.Read
        theResults2.Add(New SocioInfo 
        With {
                       .Nombre = rdr.GetString(0),
                       .LastName = rdr.GetString(1)
                       .CuentaName = rdr.GetString(2),
                       .AcctNum = rdr.GetValue(3),
                       .AcctFull = rdr.GetValue(4),
                       .Balance = rdr.GetValue(5)

       })
   End While
```

End Using

Comment: *facepalm*  I just saw it. Such an easy to spot problem... I swear to god I looked at it like 5 times before posting. Geesh. I do have a funny problem now... I press the "search" button but the program just kinda hands. No VB exception either.

Comment: I am so wary of SQL; I am scared of it haha. That's why i didn't go with Inner Join. Your reply is perfect Steve, thanks a million.